# Can I define S4 accessor `@` custom for a class?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'd like to define two S4 classes, where one contains the other. The lower class has a particular slot, say `x`, and I need `object@x` to behave differently depending on whether `object` is the lower class or the wrapper class. For example:

```
setClass("foo",
         contains = "numeric",
         slots = c(x = "character"))

setClass("bar",
         contains = "foo")

ff <- new("foo", 1:10, x = "abc")

bb <- new("bar", ff)
```

Now, from this I get:

```
> ff@x
[1] "abc"
> bb@x
[1] "abc"
```

What I'd like is when calling `bb@x`, to intercept the `"abc"` and modify it, such that `bb@x` produces something different than `ff@x`.

I tried setting a custom `@` method for `bar`:

```
setMethod("@", signature(x = "bar"),
          function(x, slot) {
            out <- x@slot
            if (slot == "x") {
              out <- toupper(out)
            }
            out
          })
```

but it fails with this error:

```
> Error in setGeneric(f, where = where) : 
  must supply a function skeleton for ‘@’, explicitly or via an existing function
```

I tried using `method.skeleton`, but this errors as well:

```
> method.skeleton("@", "bar")
Error in genericForBasic(name) : 
  methods may not be defined for primitive function ‘@’ in this version of R
```

Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Having `@` behave differently depend on different object is, in my opinion, a very bad design choice.
Why don't you make a brand new function for example `getx` as follow:

```r
setGeneric("getx", function(object) object@x)
setMethod("getx", "bar", function(object) toupper(object@x))
setGeneric("getx<-", function(object, value) {
    object@x <- value
    
    object
})

# test drive
getx(ff) # abc
getx(bb) # ABC
getx(bb) <- "zxcm"
getx(bb) # ZXCM
```